# Javascript - scroll to element after the page has loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a subpage with sections and sidebar with links to each section on every page. I am scrolling to each of them like so:

```
function scrollToElement(element) {
  if($(element) && $(element).offset()) {

    $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(element).offset().top - 80
    });
  }
}

$('.anchor-links').click(function() {
  var element = $(this).attr('id').split('-');

  if (element[0] == 'download') {
    $("html, body").animate({
      scrollTop: 0
    });
  } else {
    scrollToElement('#' + element[0]);
  }
});
```

This are the links in the sidebar on each page:

```
<div class="slideout-menu">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="/subpage#download" class="anchor-links" id="download-link">Last ned</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/subpage#about" class="anchor-links" id="about-link">Om oss</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/subpage#faq" class="anchor-links" id="faq-link">Spørsmål og svar</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/subpage#contact" class="anchor-links" id="contact-link">Kontakt</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/all">Se alle magasiner</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And this is my subpage:

```
<div class="background-container show-for-medium" id="download">
  <img src="/uploads/{{ $subpage->cover }}" alt="" />
</div>

@section('topBar')
  @include('customer.layouts.partials.top-bar')
@show

<div class="panel">
  @section('alexBox')
    @include('customer.layouts.partials.alex-box')
  @show

  @section('availability')
    @include('customer.layouts.partials.availability-info')
  @show
</div>
<section class="row faq">
  <div class="small-12 medium-10">
    <div class="subpage-section" id="about">
      {!! $subpage->about !!}
    </div>
    <div class="subpage-section" id="faq">
      {!! $subpage->faq !!}
    </div>
    <div class="subpage-section" id="contact">
      {!! $subpage->contact !!}
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Since, the `navbar` has a `height` of `80px`, I have set it up in the script to scroll to the `navbar` on navigating to each section other than download which is the top most section. When I am navigating to a section from another page on small screens, it doesn't scroll all the way to the bottom of navbar, so I can see the content of the above section. This happens only on small screens and only on navigating to some section from another page, if I am on the same page or navigating from another page on the big screen, then it works fine.
When I do `console.log($(element).offset().top);` I get different values for when I navigate to section from another page, then it is:

```
983.46875
```

And when I am on the subpage already, then it is:

```
1151.46875
```

this is where I am logging that:

```
function scrollToElement(element) {
  if($(element) && $(element).offset()) {
    console.log($(element).offset().top);
    $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(element).offset().top - 80
    });
  }
}
```

Since, I am dynamically creating and hiding some elements on the subpage I think the wrong offset comes from that, because I guess it gets the offset before all the elements are created. This is the script that does that:

```
//switch app and google store buttons
function shopButtons () {
  if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)) {
    $('.js-store-link').attr('href', 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=myapp.areader');
    $('.js-store-img').attr('src', '/img/google-store.svg');
  }

  if (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPod/i)) {
    $('.js-store-link').attr('href', 'https://itunes.apple.com/no/app/myapp+/id777109367?mt=8');
    $('.js-store-img').attr('src', '/img/app-store.svg');
  }

}

$(document).ready(function(){
shopButtons();

  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://apiEndpoint/13/salesposter.json' ,
    data : { search: 'test' },
    dataType: 'json',

    success : function(json) {
      var partner = json.partner;
      var posterName = json.name;
      $('#posterName').text(posterName);
      var metaArray = json.metadata;
      $('.meta3').attr('href', metaArray[0].value);
      $('.spid-login').attr('href', 'https://payment.schibsted.no/flow/login/');

      metaArray.forEach(function(item, index, array){
        $('.meta'+item.prio).html(item.value);
      });
    }
  });

  //hide store buttons in alex box on subpages
  if (window.location.pathname.includes('/subpage')) {
    var element = $('#' + window.location.hash.substr(1));
    scrollToElement(element);
    $('.js-alex-box-store-buttons').hide();
  }
});
```

But not sure how to fix that?
I have tried with wrapping the call to `scrollElement()` from this script  with the `window.onload` function, so that it executes after the page is completely loaded, but that didn't help, function wasn't called at all then. I have also tried by placing the whole function inside the `success` method of the `ajax` call, but then it scrolls all the way to the top.

Comment: Not sure you need JavaScript? If you have a single element with `contact` as it ID the page should scroll to it/focus on it. When `#contact` is clicked.

Comment: I need javascript for it so that I can scroll exactly to the bottom of the navbar, otherwise it would scroll underneath the navbar, since it has postion:fixed

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle or codebin with some css?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As mentioned in your comments, that you need javascript for the fixed navbar. You need to wait until the `element is defined`. Otherwise you will get his `null-pointer-exception`. So you only can execute the `scrollToElement()` in the `document.ready` function or later.

```
metaArray.forEach(function(item, index, array) {     
    $('.meta'+item.prio).html(item.value); 
});
```

is asynchronous. I think that your `.meta-elements` have no height at `document.ready`, when you scroll to your element with `scrollToElement(...)`. Try to add the function into your `success:` function.

Example for jQuery:

```js
var isSubpage = window.location.pathname.indexOf("subpage") >= 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
  var element = window.location.hash;
  scrollToElement(element);

  $('.anchor-links').click(function(event) {
    if(isSubpage){
      event.preventDefault()
      var element = $(this).attr('id').split('-');

      if (element[0] == 'download') {
        $("html, body").animate({
          scrollTop: 0
        });
      } else {
        scrollToElement('#' + element[0]);
      }
    }
  });
});

function scrollToElement(element) {
  if($(element) && $(element).offset())
  $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(element).offset().top - 80
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slideout-menu">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="/subpage#download" class="anchor-links" id="download-link">Last ned</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/subpage#about" class="anchor-links" id="about-link">Om oss</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/subpage#faq" class="anchor-links" id="faq-link">Spørsmål og svar</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/subpage#contact" class="anchor-links" id="contact-link">Kontakt</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/all">Se alle magasiner</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: But how do I do that, your example just shows native html hash navigation, but I need to use custom scroll to element, because of the navbar. How can I fix that it is not navigating to it from other page? I have added check if the element is made, but that doesn't help my issue:       ```if (element) {
    scrollToElement(element);
  }```

Comment: I added a jquery solution. First you need to check if you are on your `subpage` (firstline), then add the `click eventhandler` when the document is ready. And the error came up, when the `window.location.hash` was empty. I added an `if-statement` to check if the element exists and if its `offset()` is defined.

Comment: it still gives the same result, it scrolls only as it should when I am on the subpage already

Comment: `metaArray.forEach(function(item, index, array){ $('.meta'+item.prio).html(item.value); });` is asynchron. I think that your `.meta`-elements have no height at `document.ready`, when you scroll to your element with `scrollToElement(...)`. Try to add the function into your `success:`-function. And tell me what kind of effect it has.

Comment: As well as the images you load after the `document.ready` with `shopButtons()`. It will expand your content, when the `document` is `ready`.

Comment: I managed to fix after adding everything to success function. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: May you mark my answer as correct, i added the answer from the comments :-) You re welcome